# Replacing a div that is called by jQuery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list object and each contains an `upvote` div that is called `onclick` by my jQuery (I essentially flip the vote button in each div and asynchronously change the vote for that div via Ajax).

All object divs are contained within `row.replace` which I use to sort the objects asynchronously. The thing is that once I click on the sorter and sort the content of the `.row.replace` div, the upvote divs in the sorted list of objects stop getting called `onclick` ie. I can upvote and remove my upvote before sorting with jQuery+ajax, once the sort is applied and the contents of the div are replaced, my upvote button stops working.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.sorter').click(function () {
    $('.row.replace').empty();
    $('.row.replace').append("<br><br><br><br><p align='center'><img id='theImg' src='/media/loading1.gif'/></p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>");
    var sort = $(this).attr("name");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/filter_home/" + "Lunch" + "/" + "TrendingNow" + "/",
      data: {
        'name': 'me',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (json) {
        //loop through json object
        //alert("yoo");
        $('.row.replace').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
          $('.row.replace').append("<div class='showroom-item span3'> <div class='thumbnail'> <img class='food_pic' src='/media/" + json[i].fields.image + "' alt='Portfolio Image'> <div class='span3c'> <a><b>" + json[i].fields.name + "</b> </a> </div> <div class='span3d'> posted by <a><b>" + json[i].fields.creator.username + "</b></a> </div> <div class='span3c'> <div class='btn-group'> <div class='flip flip" + json[i].pk + "'> <div class='card'> {% if 0 %} <div class='face front'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-grove-one upvote' id='upvote' name='" + json[i].pk + "'>Upvoted <i class='glyphicons thumbs_up'><i></i></i><i class='vote-count" + json[i].pk + "'>" + json[i].fields.other_votes + "</i></a></button> </div> <div class='face back'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-grove-two upvote' id='upvote' name='" + json[i].pk + "'>Upvote <i class='glyphicons thumbs_up'><i></i></i><i class='vote-count" + json[i].pk + "'>" + json[i].fields.other_votes + " </i></a></button> </div> {% else %} <div class='face front'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-grove-two upvote' id='upvote' name='" + json[i].pk + "'>Upvote <i class='glyphicons thumbs_up'><i></i></i><i class='vote-count" + json[i].pk + "'>" + json[i].fields.other_votes + " </i></a></button> </div> <div class='face back'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-grove-one upvote' id='upvote' name='" + json[i].pk + "'>Upvoted <i class='glyphicons thumbs_up'><i></i></i><i class='vote-count" + json[i].pk + "'>" + json[i].fields.other_votes + "</i></a></button> </div> {% endif %} </div> </div> </div> <div class='btn-group'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-grove-two'><i class='glyphicons comments'><i></i></i>" + json[i].fields.comment_count + "</a></button> </div> </div> </div> </div>");
        }
        //json[i].fields.name
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
        alert("oops, something went wrong! Please try again.");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
  $('.upvote').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).attr("name");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/upvote/" + x + "/",
      data: {
        'name': 'me',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (json) {
        var y = "vote-count" + x;;
        $('i[class= "' + y + '"]').text(json.vote_count);
        //flip button
        $('.flip' + x).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
        alert("oops, something went wrong! Please try again.");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` event handler only binds to elements that exist in the DOM when the function is actually called. You need to use a [delegated `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event listener to bind to future elements as well. So for your code:

```
$('.upvote').click(function(){
```

change to:

```
$("body").on("click", '.upvote', function(event){
```

Should catch future click events. I'm using "body" as the outer selector because I don't know what your HTML looks like, but it's best to "outer-bind" to the nearest ancestor to the '.upvote`elements (so if they are all contained in a`ul` with id "vote-list" bind to that instead of "body").